# Show that subgroups of $G/H$ has the form $K/H$ where $H\subset K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a normal subgroup.I am trying to find all the normal subgroups of $G/H$.I know that for any subgroup $K\supset H$,$K/H$ is a subgroup of $G$.But I want to show that the set of all subgroups is precisely the elements $K/H$,where $H\subset K$.But I am not sure how to prove it.Can someone help me?

I have showed that if $\overline H$ is a subgroup of $G/N$,then consider $q:G\to G/N$.Take $H=q^{-1}(\overline H)$.Let $xN\in \overline H\implies q(x)\in \overline H\implies x\in q^{-1}(\overline H)=H$,Thus $xN\in H/N$ ,So we showed $\overline H\subset H/N$,how to show the converse?

Answer (score 3):

This is part of what is called the "correspondence theorem".

Here is a hint: Let $X$ be a subgroup of $G/H$. Show that $K = \{g \in G: gH \in X\}$ is a subgroup of $G/H$ and $X = K/H$.